# How can i display previous entered comments in the textfield in jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a jsp page it is having one textfield to enter comments. When i click submit button it is giving some validation errors. But previous entered comments are not displaying it is comming as blank text field. How can i display previous entered comments in the same page.

Comment: Add text to `textarea` when rebuilding JSP page!  Silly!

Answer (score 0):

Mainly there can be two possiblitiies

1. You are using javascript validation and on wrong data you might setting value to blank.
2. You might be using server side validation and on wrong data you might be resetting the field that is binded with that textbox you can handle it..

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to same page, you just set the value in session at server. 
Read from session attribute and set it in jsp. You need to make sure that this value is empty by default.

This is plain jsp syntax. 
< input type="text" name="abc" value="<%=session.getAttribute('respValue')%>" />
You can use jsp tags as well.

Hope this answer helps you.